# Chrome Extension with Webpack 4 generate wrong output

Tags: webpack, google-chrome-extension

### My webpack configuration ..

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        background: ['babel-polyfill', resolve('src', 'background.js')],
    },
    output: {
        path: resolve('dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: './',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    ],
    resolve: {extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']},
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            include: ['src'],
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {cacheDirectory: true},
            },
        }],
    },
};
```

### My background file ...

```
console.log('Background ready!'); // Exepect to print this!!
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ color: '#3aa757' }, () => {
    console.log('The color is green.');
  });

  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, () => {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
      conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
        pageUrl: { hostEquals: 'developer.chrome.com' },
      }),
      ],
      actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()], 
    }]);
  });
});
```

### My Manifest..

```
{
  "name": "..",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "..",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "declarativeContent",
    "storage"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

## Problem...

When I load my extension .. nothing are executed...

[image]

Here is my background.js generated by Webpack...

[image]

Comment: I don't know webpack, but the original code is correct so you might want to configure webpack to pass the file unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

I found that for me, webpack 4 was creating its runtime in a separate bundle. So I changed

```
optimization : {
  runtimeChunk : true,
},
```

in webpack config, to:

```
optimization : {
  runtimeChunk : false,
},
```

This caused the webpack runtime to be part of the output bundle and executed by chrome.